# Политика паролей Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, password

Необходимо в админке веб приложения реализовать возможность изменения парольной политики. Т.е. изменение ограничений на пароли пользователей системы (на их длину, регистр, запрещённые символы, срок действия, допустимое количество попыток входа и т.д.).

Есть ли в Spring Security какой-то функционал для реализации такой задачи? И если нет, то как лучше её реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Security такой функционал не предоставляет. Она занимается только вопросами аутентификации и авторизации.

Проверку политики пароля можно организовать используя формы и стандартные механизмы валидации. Это зависит от того как вы храните эту информация.

Допустимое количество попыток входа, срок действия через реализацию **AuthenticationFailureHandler** и/или **AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider**.